# array_map and htmlentities

Tags: php, arrays, html-entities

I've been trying using `array_map` to **convert characters to HTML entities** with `htmlentities()` like this:

```
$lang = array_map('htmlentities', $lang);
```

My array looks like this:

```
$lang = array();
$lang['var_char1']['varchar2'] = 'Some Text';
```

But I keep getting this **errors**:

> Warning: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
>   in /home/user/public_html/foo/lang/en.inc.php on line 1335

Does anyone know what could be the problem? Thank you!

Comment: You are using nested arrays. It'll work if you use normal ones

Comment: Are you intending to do `htmlentities()` on every element of the multidimensional `$lang` array? If so, you'll need something recursive rather than a flat `array_map()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because $lang is a two dimensional array, so it won't work

For two dimensional array you need to use for loop

```
foreach($$lang as &$l):
    $l = array_map('htmlentities', $l);
}
```

Answer (score 31):

Use [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php). `array_map` doesn't work with multidimensional arrays:

```
array_walk_recursive($lang, function (&$value) {
    $value = htmlentities($value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$lang['var_char1']['varchar2']` defines a multidimensional array, so each element of `$lang` is also an array. `array_map()` iterates through `$lang`, passing an array to `htmlentities()` instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

[array_map()](https://www.php.net/array_map) doesn't work recursively. If you know your array is always two levels deep you could loop through it and use array_map on the sub-arrays.

Answer (score 1):

if you like quotes

```
function stripslashes_array(&$arr) {
    array_walk_recursive($arr, function (&$val) {
        $val = htmlentities($val, ENT_QUOTES);
    });
}
```

multiple array in post, get, dll

```
stripslashes_array($_POST);

stripslashes_array($_GET);

stripslashes_array($_REQUEST);

stripslashes_array($_COOKIE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Each element in $lang is an array, so the function you pass to array_map should take an array as an argument. That is not the case for 'htmlentities' which takes a string.

You can:

```
$map_htmlentities = function(array) { return array_map('htmlentities', array); };
```

and then

```
$lang = array_map($map_htmlentities, $lang);
```

From PHP 7.4 on you can use lambdas:

```
$lang = array_map(fn($arr) => array_map('htmlentities', $arr), $lang);
```