# Whether a website search coded with PHP (with .txt file as indexing file) vulnerable to any attacks (like SQL Injection & XSS)?

Tags: php, security, xss, sql-injection

I have a website search coded with PHP. It is essentially a PHP-AJAX search which gets triggered on `onkeyup` event of the search input field. The `onkeyup` triggers an AJAX call to a PHP file which reads `indexes-file.txt` file containing the indexes, by using PHP's `file()` function.

Although, here I am not dealing with Database, so I think that there is no chance for SQL-Injection or an XSS attack (correct me if I am wrong).

Also, I know about `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and `htmlentities()` function, their importance, and use case. What I am trying to know is whether this particular PHP-AJAX method is vulnerable or not.

Further, is there any other type of vulnerability exists in this type of case apart from server-side vulnerabilities?

The `onkeyup` function is:

```
function results(str) {
  var search_term = $("#search")
    .val()
    .trim();

  if (search_term == "") {
    // ...
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      url: "websearch.php",
      type: "post",
      data: {
        string: search_term
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(returnData) {
        for(var i in returnData) {
                for(var j in returnData[i]) {
                    $('#results').append('<div><a target="_blank" href="'+returnData[i][j]+'">'+Object.keys(returnData[i])+'</a></div>');
                }
            }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

the `indexes-file.txt` contains:

```
books*books.php  
newspaper*newspaper.php  
download manual*manual.php  
...
```

and my `websearch.php` file contains:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    $indexes = 'indexes-file.txt';
    $index_array = file($indexes, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    foreach($index_array as $st) {
        $section = explode('*', $st);
        $k = $section[0];
        $kklink = $section[1];
        $l_arr[] = array($k => $kklink);
    }

    //Get the search term from "string" POST variable.
    $var1 = isset($_POST['string']) ? trim($_POST['string']) : '';

    $webresults = array();

    //Loop through our lookup array.

    foreach($l_arr as $kk){
        //If the search term is present.
         if(stristr(key($kk), $var1)){
             //Add it to the results array.
            foreach($kk as $value) {
                 $webresults[] = array(key($kk) => $value);
            }
        }
     }

    //Display the results in JSON format so to parse it with JavaScript.
    echo json_encode($webresults);
?>
```

Comment: What happens with `$var1`? Is it output on the browser? If so XSS exists. If there is no SQL there cant be a SQL injection. Your text files likely are less secure than a DB, if there is sensitive data there check the access levels.

Comment: you are not showing enough of websearch.php for anyone to answer your question

Comment: Keep in mind that most of `php.ini`'s *default* settings make a site vulnerable, so if anything, that would be the first place you'd want to check. Check [OWASP](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/PHP_Configuration_Cheat_Sheet.md) for reference.

Comment: @user3783243 I have updated the post. You can now check it. I previously removed all the extra code (for simplicity) which aren't vulnerable but as I see I was rated -1 for this thing only so I added it back.

Comment: @lufc I have updated the post. You can now check it. I previously removed all the extra code (for simplicity) which aren't vulnerable but as I see I was rated -1 for this thing only so I added it back.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I agree to it and I'll check that part as well. Currently, I want to know whether this PHP-AJAX way is secure or not. By the way, I've updated the code, see if you can help more.

Comment: @user3783243 I don't feel that search indexes are sensitive data for me. The worst-case would be, he will end up deleting or editing the file. Is that so?

Comment: I think `$string` should be `$var1`. Other than that it looks OK to me.

Comment: @lufc correct. I forgot to change it while posting here. However, my query is about the vulnerability of this PHP-AJAX way. Any comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not dealling with database it may be not vulnerable to sql injection but it's probably vulnerable to xss to prevent xss and script execution you should use:

**Prevent XSS**

**PHP** `htmlentities()` **Function**

basic example of filter the inputs

```
<?php 

echo '<script>alert("vulnerable");</script>'; //vulnerable to xss
?>
```

filtering the inputs with htmlentities()

```
<?php 
$input = '<script>alert("vulnerable");</script>';
echo  htmlentities($input); //not vulnerable to external input code injection scripts
?>
```

so it prevent script and html tags injection from execute on site 
[read more here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp)

for database you should use pdo with prepared statements

**Prevent SQL injection**

**Use** `PDO`
**Correctly setting up the connection**
Note that when using PDO to access a MySQL database real prepared statements are not used by default. To fix this you have to disable the emulation of prepared statements. An example of creating a connection using PDO is:

```
$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbtest;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'user', 'password');

$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

[read more here](https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Fixing your code

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    $indexes = 'indexes-file.txt';
    $index_array = file($indexes, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    foreach($index_array as $st) {
        $section = explode('*', $st);
        $k = $section[0];
        $kklink = $section[1];
        $l_arr[] = array($k => $kklink);
    }

    //Get the search term from "string" POST variable.
    $var1 = isset($_POST['string']) ? trim($_POST['string']) : '';

    $webresults = array();

    //Loop through our lookup array.

    foreach($l_arr as $kk){
        //If the search term is present.
         if(stristr(key($kk), $var1)){
             //Add it to the results array.
            foreach($kk as $value) {
                 $webresults[] = array(key($kk) => $value);
            }
        }
     }

    //Display the results in JSON format so to parse it with JavaScript.
   echo htmlentities(json_encode($webresults));
    //fixed 

?>
```

Everytime you echo something from the outside use `htmlentities`

```
echo htmlentities(json_encode($webresults));
```

Your array problem I tested with a demo json string it's working fine

```
<?php 
$webresults = 
'
{  "aliceblue": "#f0f8ff",
  "antiquewhite": "#faebd7",
  "aqua": "#00ffff",
  "aquamarine": "#7fffd4",
  "azure": "#f0ffff",
  "beige": "#f5f5dc",
  "bisque": "#ffe4c4",
  "black": "#000000",

}';

echo htmlentities(json_encode($webresults));

 ?>
```

Comment: I have tried multiple XSS examples but it seems the search is not vulnerable as it is returning an empty array on input.

So the htmlentities() function should be implemented this way:
$var1 = htmlentities(isset($_POST['string']) ? trim($_POST['string']) : '');
Correct?

Comment: yeah it's correct you should filter all inputs with `htmlentities` and also filter when return data from database and showing to user

Comment: Agreed. But I need to know in this case specifically.
Is my code vulnerable to XSS? Since I am calling it through AJAX and that seems to be non-risky even when I don't use htmlentities() function.

Comment: yeah it's just because it's being called via ajax does not mean data is not being posted or inserting, you should filter all inputs indeed

Comment: Second thing is I know about mysqli_real_escape_string() and htmlentities() function and their importance and use case. What I am trying to know is whether this particular PHP-AJAX method is vulnerable or not.

Comment: It seems correct that you implemented it at "echo json_encode(htmlentities($webresults));", otherwise, if you had added it to "$var1 = htmlentities(isset($_POST['string']) ? trim($_POST['string']) : '');" line then there could be possible problem of no match in the .txt file as it will convert all HTML entities to their equivalent codes. Like, in that case, I'd not find "doctor's manual" as it will be converted to "doctor&#039;s manual" which can't be matched in the file but its actual literals exists (i.e. doctor's manual). Thanks for the input. It helped a lot.

Comment: It seems there is some error your syntax "echo json_encode(htmlentities($webresults));" as now the PHP file is returning null for all input. Showing an error "Warning: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-website\websearch.php on line 40". Is it the problem as we are applying htmlentities() to an array?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150442/array-map-and-htmlentities) is what I found may be the possible problem as my array is a 2-dimensional array, it is leading to this error.

Comment: try to do this `echo htmlentities(json_encode($webresults));` before the json

Comment: Did so. But now the PHP isn't returning an array but this kind of output:
[{&quot;books&quot;:&quot;books.php&quot;},{&quot;newspaper&quot;:&quot;newspaper.php&quot;},{&quot;Download Manual&quot;:&quot;manual.php&quot;}]

Comment: which is equivalent to:
[{"books":"books.php"},{"newspaper":"newspaper.php"},{"Download Manual":"manual.php"}] which seems to be correct but in the JS where I am processing the output I have this code:
for(var i in returnData) {
        for(var j in returnData[i]) {
 $('#results').append('<div><a target="_blank" href="'+returnData[i][j]+'">'+Object.keys(returnData[i])+'</a></div>');
     }
    }

I have updated my post, kindly check.

Comment: I have added it inside the foreach loop before the echo json_encode($webresults); where I am saving the result to an array which eventually is passed to the JS for output. Like this:
foreach($kk as $value) {
   $webresults[] = array(htmlentities(key($kk)) => htmlentities($value));
  }
and it is working fine. Any comments?

Comment: waiting for your reply.

Comment: I think you can use your code with normal json and than return it as array and when echo each array you do `echo htmlentities($array[1]);`

Comment: OK will do and check.